# What are pdftex `\pdfmatch` rules for expansion and use of special classes?

Tags: pdftex, strmatch, regex

pdftex has a command that's potentially useful to me for searching and for splitting strings:  `\pdfmatch`.  However, I've found few working examples on the internet.  I do have the basic use figured out.  For example, borrowing a regex from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers, these lines:

```
\count255=\pdfmatch {[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+} {-4.06}
\message{\number\count255, \pdflastmatch0, \pdflastmatch1}
\end
```

produce this output:  `1, 0->-4.06, 1->4`

My question is:  has anyone figured out the expansion rules for `\pdfmatch` and whether it can handle character classes like `[:alnum:]`?

I ask about character classes because pdftex's search is supposedly posix-compatable.  According to this page, character classes are in the posix standard: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions. Other pages indicate the classes are locale-dependent.  I can't get them to work with `\pdfmatch` at all, and I suspect I'm not doing anything wrong; they're just not supported by pdftex.

A few other discoveries I've made which are related to the expansion part of my question:  `^` and `$` work as anchors without any changes to their catcodes.  I've also discovered that `\pdfmatch` does at least some expansion.  You can't use `\$` as an anchor when it comes from the plain TeX `\chardef`. But if changed to `\def\${$}` (no fancy verbatim), then `$` and `\$` behave similarly.

The above makes we wonder if expansion is full like an `\edef` or just one-level like an `\ifx`, and which of TeX's special characters have to be escaped or passed in as catcode12.  Braces, even when balanced, are especially puzzling.  Working examples of `\strmatch` or rules would be most appreciated.

P.S.  I'm aware of regex solutions with luatex.  It's specifically pdftex I'm wondering about. Thanks!

Comment: I think everything is expanded then taken as a string ignoring catcodes (like `\meaning` or `\detokenize` on the edef expansion, then regex work on the resulting string. so a chardefed `\$`  would not expand so would be `\$` in the regex  not `$`

Comment: from the source readme: 
Note that none of the wide-character and i18n functionality which is
built when this is part of glibc gets compiled. Thus things like
character classes most probably work only for single-byte codepages.

Answer (score 3):

The regex source code in the pdftex sources has some optional support for character classes but does not have locale support so is not reliably usable with non ascii characters, any UTF-8 input will be seen as multiple bytes not the unicode characters.

```
\pdfmatch {[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+} {-4.06}
\immediate\write500{1: \pdflastmatch0, \pdflastmatch1}

% [:digit:] is [:digt]  checking for those literal characters
\pdfmatch {[+-]?([:digit:]*[.])?[:digit:]+} {-dddg:ii.ggg}
\immediate\write500{2: \pdflastmatch0, \pdflastmatch1}

% [[:digit:]] is digit class
\pdfmatch {[+-]?([[:digit:]]*[.])?[[:digit:]]+} {-4.06}
\immediate\write500{3: \pdflastmatch0, \pdflastmatch1}

% full expansion happens for both arguments before regex processing
\def\aaa{[0-9]*[.]}
\def\bbb{[+-]?(\aaa)?}
\def\ccc{\bbb[0-9]+}

\def\DDD{4}
\def\EEE{06}
\def\FFF{-\DDD.\EEE}

\pdfmatch {\ccc} {\FFF}
\immediate\write500{4: \pdflastmatch0, \pdflastmatch1}

\chardef\DOLLAR=`$

\pdfmatch {\DOLLAR} {\$}
\immediate\write500{5: \pdflastmatch0}

\pdfmatch {\DOLLAR} {.D.*R}
\immediate\write500{6: \pdflastmatch0}


\pdfmatch {\DOLLAR} {.*}
\immediate\write500{7: \pdflastmatch0}


\pdfmatch {abc\DOLLAR} {a.*}
\immediate\write500{8: \pdflastmatch0}


\end
```

produces

```
1: 0->-4.06, 1->4.
2: 0->-dddg:ii.ggg, 1->dddg:ii.
3: 0->-4.06, 1->4.
4: 0->-4.06, 1->4.
5: -1->
6: -1->
7: -1->
8: -1->
```

where test 2 shows `[:digit:]` is not a character class but simply that set of characters `: d i g t`

test 3 shows `[[:digit:]]` is the character class (thanks @egreg)

Test 4 shows that both the string and the regex are fully expanded before regex processing starts.

Tests 5-8 with the non expandable chardef token `\DOLLAR` show that if the expansion does not consist purely of character tokens, nothing matches.

Comment: @egreg thanks, updated

Comment: I don't know how to choose an answer here, it's all very helpful.

Comment: @DanLevin when it's a choice between me and egreg, there is always an obvious choice to pick:-)

Comment: For anyone else reading this, you might think `\detokenize` will get you a sanitized regex string for `\pdfmatch`.  Just be aware that any control-_words_ will get a space added after them, likely breaking the regex.  I've been changing catcodes and using `\scantokens`, or using `\string\cs`, to get the category 12 tokens I want for the regex.  I presume LaTeX's `\verb` command could be used also.

I haven't yet experimented with `\expandafter\pdfmatch\expandafter{\re}{...}` or `\edef\next{\noexpand\pdfmatch...}\next`, and I'll be interested to see if all rules hold there.

Comment: Ok @DavidCarlisle, I'll follow your suggestion and pick egreg (smile).  Actually, I'm embarrassed I couldn't get the characters classes to work.  I was carelessly not doubling the square brackets.  The information you posted is exactly what I was looking for, and I'm sure it will be a great reference for others.

Comment: @DanLevin to get `\b` without a space easiest is probably to use `\string\b`you don't need the `\expandafter` as the arguments will expand first anyway

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for `\pdfmatch` is stated on page 45 of the manual (rev. 905)

`\pdfmatch` `[ icase ] [ subcount` ⟨integer⟩ `]` ⟨general text⟩ ⟨general text⟩ (expandable)

Since both arguments are ⟨general text⟩, their content is subject to full expansion like what happens for `\message`.

Thus, if you need to escape a character for making a regex, say `\+` to match a literal `+`, you need `\noexpand\+` or `[+]` (see the example below).

Character classes `[:alpha:]`, `[:digit:]` and `[:alnum:]` are supported (with double brackets, of course).

In order to match the end of string you just use `$`, and the start of the string is `^`.

What character set? Recall that `pdftex` is 8-bit, so UTF-8 support is out of the question (but in some cases it can work with `pdflatex`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\count255=\pdfmatch{[[:digit:]]x}{1x2y}
\message{^^J1: \the\count255; \pdflastmatch0}

\count255=\pdfmatch{[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]}{12y}
\message{^^J2: \the\count255; \pdflastmatch0}

\count255=\pdfmatch{[[:alnum:]]*\noexpand\+}{a2c+d3f+}
\message{^^J3: \the\count255; \pdflastmatch0}

\count255=\pdfmatch{[[:alnum:]]*[+]$}{a2c+d3f+}
\message{^^J4: \the\count255; \pdflastmatch0}

\count255=\pdfmatch{^[[:alnum:]]*\noexpand\+}{a2c+d3f+}
\message{^^J5: \the\count255; \pdflastmatch0}

\count255=\pdfmatch{à}{aàa}
\message{^^J6: \the\count255; \pdflastmatch0}

\stop
```

The console will print

```
1: 1; 0->1x
2: 1; 1->2y
3: 1; 0->a2c+
4: 1; 4->d3f+
5: 1; 0->a2c+
6: 1; 1->à
```

If you use

```
\pdfmatch{\unexpanded{<regex>}}{<text>}
```

the ⟨regex⟩ can be in the standard POSIX syntax. For instance, the example 3 above can be

```
\count255=\pdfmatch{\unexpanded{[[:alnum:]]*\+}}{a2c+d3f+}
```